# R: visualizing regression lines while controlling for covariates

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, data-visualization

I am working with R, where I have a linear regression model specified in the following way:

```
mod = lm (data = dat, test_score ~ age + comprehension_score + IQ_score)
```

PART 1:
I would like to plot the regression line for `test_score` (Y axis) based on the `age` (X axis) predictor while controlling for `comprehension_score` and `IQ_score`, which are my covariates. I don't need to have the covariates anywhere in my plot, I just need them to control for them when calculating the effects of my main predictor of interest.

PART 2:
Now imagine I have three similar models, with `test_score1`, `test_score2`, and `test_score3` as DVs and the same `age`, `comprehension_score`, and `IQ_score` for each one (that is, the same participants completed all three tests). How can I plot the regression lines of each test score as predicted by age, while controlling for my covariates on the same graph? That is, I want to create three plots like the one I described in part 1, and then make them overlap on the same graph so that I can visually compare them. How can I get this in R?

Comment: closely related, check this one https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/logit-regression/

Comment: Can you provide an example dataset for people to work with?